# How to retrieve list(s) that contains specific query items

Tags: python, list, search

I am trying to group list of items relevant to a query item. Below is an example of the problem and my attempt at it:

```
>>> _list=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
>>> querylist=[1,2,4]
>>> relvant=[]
>>> for x in querylist:
        for y in _list:
            if x in y:
                relvant.append(y)
```

My output:

```
>>> relvant
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4]]
```

Desired output:

```
[[[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]],[[2, 3, 4]]]
```

The issue is after each loop of a query item, I expected the relevant lists to be grouped but that isn't the case with my attempt.

Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it's clearer to use a list comprehension:

```
>>> _list = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
>>> querylist = [1,2,4]
>>> [[l for l in _list if x in l] for x in querylist]
[[[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]], [[2, 3, 4]]]
```

The inner expression `[l for l in _list if x in l]` describes the list of all sublists that contain `x`. The outer expression's job is to get that list for all values of `x` in the query list.

Answer (score 3):

By making minimal changes in the code provided you can create new dummy list to store values and at end of each inner loop iteration you just append it to the main list.

```
_list=[[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
querylist=[1,2,4]
relvant=[]
for x in querylist:
    dummy = []
    for y in _list:
        if x in y:
            dummy.append(y)
    relvant.append(dummy)

print relvant
>>> [[[1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4]],[[2, 3, 4]]]
```